# Infinite loops while validating input

Tags: java

I'm having an issue with input validation. I wrote a program in which two people are simulating a dice game. The actual game code is alright but I just don't know why I am having an infinite loop when I'm trying to run the program again. Basically, if the user input "Y" the program will run again, if they input "N", the program will end and if they enter anything other than Y or N, the prompt, "Would you like to play again?" Is the following code right or do I need to change it up a bit(I'm mainly referring to the input validation code)?

```
do{
        System.out.print("Would you like to play again? (Y/N): ");
        String command = input.next();
        if(input.hasNextLine()){
            if(command.equals("Y") || command.equals("y")){
                die1 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
                die2 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
                die3 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
                die4 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
                sum = die1 + die2;
                sum2 = die3 + die4;

                System.out.printf("%s rolled a %d and %d for a total of %d. %n", name1, die1, die2, sum);
                System.out.printf("%s rolled a %d and %d for a total of %d. %n", name2, die3, die4, sum2);

                if(sum > sum2){
                    System.out.println(name1 + " " + "won!");
                }
                else if (sum2 > sum){
                    System.out.println(name2 + " " + "won!");
                }
                else if (sum == sum2){
                    System.out.println(name1 + " " + "and" + " " + name2 + " " + "tied!");
                }

                game = input.nextLine();
        }
        else if(command.equals("N") || command.equals("n")){
            System.exit(1);
        }
        }
    }while(!validInput);
}
```

}

Edit: I deleted the entire code and just insert the piece of code that was in question but it is correct...thanks again!

Comment: `if(input.equals(YES) || input.equals(YES2)){` will never be `true` because `input` is a `Scanner` you need to call `nextLine` and store it somewhere.

Comment: Is there a way around it?

Comment: first after the question, write `String command = input.next()` and change `if(input.equals(YES) || input.equals(YES2))`, to `if(command.equals("y") || command.equals("Y"))`

Answer (score 0):

`input` is a `Scanner` object and will never equal `YES` or `YES2` which are `String` objects. You need to use `nextLine` to read the next `String` and save that value into a variable such as `response`. Then you can compare `response` to `YES` and other strings.

```
    do {
        System.out.print("Would you like to play again? (Y/N): ");
        String response = input.nextLine();
        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase(YES)) {
            die1 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            die2 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            die3 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            die4 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            sum = die1 + die2;
            sum2 = die3 + die4;

            System.out.printf("%s rolled a %d and %d for a total of %d. %n", name1, die1, die2, sum);
            System.out.printf("%s rolled a %d and %d for a total of %d. %n", name2, die3, die4, sum2);
            game = input.nextLine();
            break;
        } else if (response.equalsIgnoreCase(NO)) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    } while (validInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to get all fancy with a do-while loop, if your going to terminate the program through System.exit() you can just surround your program with a while (true) loop. Also don't see a need for a hasNextLine here. You could shorten up the input validation with an equalsIgnoreCase("y"). Also it's usually a good idea to declare your variables outside of the loop. (ie. String command; on the outside, command = "stuff" on the inside). I'm not sure how it will work in this particular case but a lot of times you'll run into errors trying to redeclare variables.

The problem with your loop though that i see is that you have no else clause that deals with input if the user enters in something other than "Y" or "N". You could an else clause at the end that terminates the program if this other input is entered, or you could simply use a continue; statement to start to program over again.